# Problems with form calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a small part of a much longer form (the Pink, Green, and Yellow boxes/arrows have been added for clarity):

**Original:**
[image]

**Marked Up:**
[image]

Basically - As numbers are entered into quarters -> checks (the pink box), the values auto sum and auto populate the read only field "Total Cash" (this is already working). Then, once the "Refunds Paid in" Field has a value entered (including zero) it auto sums with "Total Cash" and populates the "final total" Field - this is all separate for each column. That works - but I wish I didn't have to force users to enter a value in Refunds Paid in unless there IS a value. Lastly - I also need "Final Totals" from the "Deposit" and "Manager Station" columns to Auto sum to "Total to Deposit" That doesn't seem to be working at all...

Lastly - I tried to implement a button to recalculate all totals before they click "submit" to turn this into a PDF - I'm also stumped there. that has the name and ID `calc` - I'm open to any best practices solutions on any of this though. I'd be more than happy to make heavy modifications - as a newbie, a lot of this employs "seat-of-my-pants" coding.

I'm VERY new to Javascript and JQuery - so please be gentle? Code below (the portions relevant to this question, anyway):

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="label" colspan="4">Deposit / Safe / Manager Station Count</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="null"></td>
    <td class="label">Deposit</td>
    <td class="label">Manager Station</td>
    <td class="label">Safe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Quarters</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depQuarters" class="dep" tabindex="31" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="manQuarters" class="man" tabindex="41" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safeQuarters" class="safe" tabindex="51" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Coins</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depCoins" class="dep" tabindex="32" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="manCoins" class="man" tabindex="42" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safeCoins" class="safe" tabindex="52" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$1 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep1Bills" class="dep" tabindex="33" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man1Bills" class="man" tabindex="43" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe1Bills" class="safe" tabindex="53" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$5 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep5Bills" class="dep" tabindex="34" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man5Bills" class="man" tabindex="44" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe5Bills" class="safe" tabindex="54" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$10 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep10Bills" class="dep" tabindex="35" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man10Bills" class="man" tabindex="45" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe10Bills" class="safe" tabindex="55" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$20 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep20Bills" class="dep" tabindex="36" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man20Bills" class="man" tabindex="46" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe20Bills" class="safe" tabindex="56" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$50 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep50Bills" class="dep" tabindex="37" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man50Bills" class="man" tabindex="47" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe50Bills" class="safe" tabindex="57" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">$100 Bills</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="dep100Bills" class="dep" tabindex="38" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="man100Bills" class="man" tabindex="48" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safe100Bills" class="safe" tabindex="58" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Checks</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depChecks" class="dep" tabindex="39" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="manChecks" class="man" tabindex="49" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safeChecks" class="safe" tabindex="59" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Total Cash</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depTotal" id="depTotal" class="depFinalFactor" readonly /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" id="manTotal" name="manTotal" class="manFinalFactor" readonly /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" id="safeTotal" name="safeTotal" class="safeFinalFactor" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Refunds Paid In</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depRefunds" id="depRef" class="depFinalFactor" tabindex="40" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="manRefunds" tabindex="50" class="manFinalFactor" /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safeRefunds" tabindex="60" class="safeFinalFactor" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label">Final Total</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="depFinalTotal" id="depFinalTotal" readonly /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="manFinalTotal" id="manFinalTotal" readonly /></td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="safeFinalTotal" id="safeFinalTotal" readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="null" colspan="2"></td>
    <td class="label">Total to Deposit</td>
    <td class="field" id="totalToDeposit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="calc" id="calc" value="Recalculate Totals" />
<input style="float: right;" type="submit" name="btn_submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event

    $(".accXPT1").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".accXPT1", "#accXPT1Total");
        });
    });
    $(".accXPT2").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".accXPT2", "#accXPT2Total");
        });
    });
    $(".accXPT3").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".accXPT3", "#accXPT3Total");
        });
    });


    $(".dispXPT1").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".dispXPT1", "#dispXPT1Total");
        });
    });
    $(".dispXPT2").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".dispXPT2", "#dispXPT2Total");
        });
    });
    $(".dispXPT3").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".dispXPT3", "#dispXPT3Total");
        });
    });


    $(".dep").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".dep", "#depTotal");
        });         
    });
    $(".man").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".man", "#manTotal");
        });
    });
    $(".safe").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSumForInput(".safe", "#safeTotal");
        });
    });


    $(".depFinalFactor").keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;

        $(".depFinalFactor").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });     


        mySum = sum.toFixed(2);

        if (mySum == $("#moneyAccountedFor").val()) {
            $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "red");
        }

        $("#depFinalTotal").val(mySum);
        $("#totalToDeposit").text(mySum);
    });

    $("#calc").on("click", function() {
        var sum = 0;

        $(".depFinalFactor").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });     


        mySum = sum.toFixed(2);

        if (mySum == $("#moneyAccountedFor").val()) {
            $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "red");
        }

        $("#depFinalTotal").val(mySum);
        $("#totalToDeposit").text(mySum);
    });

    $(".manFinalFactor").keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;

        $(".manFinalFactor").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });     


        mySum = sum.toFixed(2);
        $("#manFinalTotal").val(mySum);
    });

    $(".safeFinalFactor").keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;

        $(".safeFinalFactor").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });     


        mySum = sum.toFixed(2);
        $("#safeFinalTotal").val(mySum);
    });

});

function calculateSum(myClass, myID) {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(myClass).each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }


    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    myTotal = sum.toFixed(2);
    $(myID).text(myTotal);
}

function calculateSumForInput(myClass, myID) {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(myClass).each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }


    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    myTotal = sum.toFixed(2);
    $(myID).val(myTotal);
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle if anyone wants to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/Mt9NX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That works - but I wish I didn't have to force users to enter a value
>   in Refunds Paid in unless there IS a value.

Is it all what you want?
Try out the below code

1/ Add this function

```
                function showAllTotal(){
                    var sum = 0;

                    $(".depFinalFactor").each(function() {
                    //add only if the value is number
                        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                        }
                    });     


                    mySum = sum.toFixed(2);

                    if (mySum == $("#moneyAccountedFor").val()) {
                        $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "green");
                    } else {
                        $("#totalToDeposit").css("color", "red");
                    }

                    $("#depFinalTotal").val(mySum);
                    $("#totalToDeposit").text(mySum);
                }
```

2/ Modify somewhere: add above function to each event

```
            $(".dep").each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){
                        calculateSumForInput(".dep", "#depTotal");
                        showAllTotal();
                    });         
                });
                $(".man").each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){
                        calculateSumForInput(".man", "#manTotal");
                        showAllTotal();
                    });
                });
                $(".safe").each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){
                        calculateSumForInput(".safe", "#safeTotal");
                        showAllTotal();
                    });
                });
```

3/ Replace the function at "$(".depFinalFactor").keyup(function()" with below

```
            $(".depFinalFactor").keyup(function() {
                    showAllTotal();
            });
```

What I did is moving the function that summarizes total value to a function, and I reuse it each time user begin enter the number on one of fields from table. All in your code, nothing more!

Edited: I updated your code on fiddle also.

Comment: Fixed! You are a life saver!